# migrate error : ...No migrations to apply

Tags: django, django-models, migration, django-migrations, migrate

I made some changes in the models from my apps and then entered makemigrations and migrate in the terminal.

PS C:\Users\USER 1\frist project\website> python manage.py makemigrations home
No changes detected in app 'home'
PS C:\Users\USER 1\frist project\website> python manage.py migrate
?[36;1mOperations to perform:?[0m
?[1m  Apply all migrations: ?[0maccounts, admin, auth, cart, contenttypes, home, order, sessions, taggit, thumbnail
?[36;1mRunning migrations:?[0m
No migrations to apply.

Answer (score 0):

One of the 4 possibilities here:

- No changes made to models that require migrations;
- The app is not part of the project. You need to add it to settings.py;
- Migrations already applied. If you've applied some migrations earlier, but then made some changed that don't require migrations on their own - you are back to first case of this list;
- You're trying to apply migrations to the wrong app altogether.

Comment: I think your second suggestion is not correct. Adding model in admin.py does not affect on migrations. Perhaps you meant app is not included in settings.py (installed_apps)